# A property of finite field of order $2^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are elements of a finite field of order $2^n$ with $n$ odd and $a^2+ab+b^2=0$. Is it necessary that both $a$ and $b$ must be zero ?

I understand that the field has characteristic $2$ but don't know how to use the fact that $n$ is odd, please help.

Comment: If $b$ were not 0, say, then the ratio $a/b$ is a root of $x^2 + x + 1$ (divide the equation by $b^2$). What does that tell you about the subfield ${\mathbf F}_2(a/b)$ inside your finite field?

Comment: Well, if $n$ is $2$ for example you can take $b=1$ and $a$ to be either of the elements that are neither $1$ nor $0$.

Comment: @Chris:  It was specified that $n$ is odd.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Yes, I know. The OP seemed to be unsure why this was relevant.

Comment: @Chris: Ah! Apologies.

Comment: KCd nailed it. Another equivalent way to think about this is to determine the fields $GF(2^n)$ that contain a primitive third root of unity.

Comment: @KCd, you should post your comment as an answer: it is a very nice and accurate hint for the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $b$ were not 0 then $a/b$ would be a root of $x^2 + x + 1$, which is irreducible over ${\mathbf F}_2$. Look at the size of the field ${\mathbf F}_2(a/b)$ and the size of the field you are working in that has order $2^n$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a=b$,
then $a^2+ab+b^2=3a^2=a^2=0$ and $a=0=b$, 
we are done.

Suppose that $a\neq b$.

Observe that $0=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3$.
Thus, $a^3=b^3$.

We claim that $a=0$ and $b=0$.

If $a\neq 0$,
then $(a^{-1}b)^3=1$ and the multiplicative order of $a^{-1}b$ 
in the multiplicative group $F-\{0\}$ is $1$
because $3\not\mid |F-\{0\}|=2^n-1$.
Hence, $a^{-1}b=1$ and $a=b$,
a contradiction.
Therefore, $a=0$.
By a similar argument, we have $b=0$.

Comment: And $3\nmid 2^n-1$ because $n$ is odd. Right.