# About a field of order $2^{n}$ with $n$ an odd integer and an additional property

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I'm new in the world of fields (so I don't have any strong theorem at my disposal) and I've got stuck in this problem:

> Given a field of order $2^{n}$ with $n$ an odd integer and $a,b$
>   elements in the field such that $a^2+ab+b^2=0$, prove that $a=b=0$.

I've found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263733/a-property-of-finite-field-of-order-2n)  but in the book i'm studying from (Gallian's book) we've not touched that stuff, the only thing I can use is that the characteristic is two and the fact that this fields forms a group under multiplication. I'm looking for something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659797/field-of-order-8-a2abb2-0-implies-a-0-and-b-0) in the general case.

Please, if someone can help me that would be great.

Comment: Do you know *how* fields of order $\;p^n\;,\;\;p$ a prime, are constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof that introduces degrees, irreducible polynomials, etc. can be "written down" to an explicit calculation.

If either $a,b$ is zero, then $a^2 + ab + b^2 = 0$ implies both are.  So assume neither $a,b$ is zero, and in particular $x = a/b$ is nonzero.

As before $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$, or as we are in characteristic 2, $x^2 = x+1$ and $x(x+1) = 1$.  That is, in the multiplicative group of the field, $x$ has order 3:

$$ x^3 = x(x+1) = 1 $$

Therefore 3 must divide the order of the multiplicative group $2^n-1$.  But this is only possible when $n$ is even by a simple congruence calculation, $2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! So this arguments is just a particular case (or "the proof") of the theorem @Andrea was talking about!! Thank you very much. (All other answers were great too).

Comment: Very nice and elementary. +1

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do it entirely with group theory: Suppose that $a \neq b$ .  Notice that $a^{3}-b^{3} = (a-b)(a^{2}+ab+b^{2})=0,$ so $a^{3} = b^{3}.$ We claim that $m = 2^{n }-1$ must be divisible by $3.$ This is the order of the order of the multiplicative group of the field containing $a$ and $b,$ so we have $a^{m} = b^{m} = 1.$ Now if $3$ does not divide $m,$ then we have $3x + my = 1$ for integers $x$ and $y.$ Then $a = a^{3x+my} = a^{3x} = b^{3x} = b^{3x+my} = b^{1} = b,$ a contradiction. Hence $3$ divides $2^{n}-1,$ so as noted by others $n$ must be even.

Comment: Such a great answer too, extremely simple and it's great because it uses simple arguments not from field theory. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the field $\Bbb F$ has $2^n$ elements, it is an extension of degree $n$ of the field $\Bbb F_2$ with $2$ elements.

If $a$ and $b$ are in $\Bbb F$ and non zero, their ratio $x=a/b\in\Bbb F$ is a root of the polynomial $X^2+X+1\in\Bbb F_2[X]$ which is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$. Thus $x$ generates the (unique) quadratic extension $\Bbb F_4$ of $\Bbb F_2$. But since $n$ is odd $\Bbb F$ cannot contain $\Bbb F_4$.

Thus the only possibility left is that $a=b=0$.

Comment: This is *exactly* the argument the OP said he can't use as he hasn't yet studied this...

Comment: Darn, I guess I should learn to follow links ....

Comment: @AndreaMori I'm really thankful with your answer, but I'm looking for a "simpler" argument, I mean, in this moment I don't know about the meaning of "irreducible" or "quadratic extension" or theorem related with those terms, In the second link is a proof of the case in which $n=3$, i'm looking for something loke that but in the general case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Devilathor: sorry, I rushed in the answer without checking your links. My bad. It is likely that the argument using the fact that the given polynomial is a factor of $a^3-b^3$ can be generalized, but I assure you that once you have got familiarity with the basics of field theory (degree of an extension, extending a field with a root of a polynomial) the solution I gave will look very simple.

Comment: @AndreaMori: Thanks for your respond. I guess your solution is the "standard" one and is pretty simple (no offense), but not being able to solve it without background theory feels annoying because that problem in the book is supposed to be solved without that background. The theory helps us and is extremely useful for us, but the point here is to prove this with a lot of effort without relatively strong theorems for seeing it later being proved in two lines by a strong argument like yours. Again, thanks for you help!.